# Simulink integration with variable bounds

Tags: matlab, simulink, integral, numerical-integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJzTC.png)

I need to implement a integral in my simulink model with a variable upper bound. The upper bound is a signal in my model which gets smaller every step.
I tried to put the variable in the workspace (simout-block) and solve the integral in matlab (syma sigma tf; f = .....; int(f, t0, tf);). Then i tried to take the solved integral with simin-block.

Im new to the simulink thing. Would this proceed will be the right for my problem? Im not sure if the integral will get solved for every step.
Besides that: i get a error for my simin-block because the input format of my solved integral is not supported.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.